# can't assign fetch() data to vue property

Tags: vue.js

I'm learning fetch() and I've managed to grab some data from the Star Wars API. I want to assign the data returned to some Vue properties. However they are coming back as null.

By default I set them to null, however once the fetch has initiated the values don't update. Does anyone know why? I've been following this tutorial https://scotch.io/@bedakb/lets-build-type-ahead-component-with-vuejs-2-and-fetch-api and have assigned my data in the same way.

https://jsfiddle.net/Ltwen65g/

The JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
        name: null,
    height: null
  },
  methods: {
        getData() {
        fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/people/1')
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            this.name = data.name;
            this.height = data.height;
          })
    },
    consoleLog() {
        console.log(this.name, this.height);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
        this.getData()
    this.consoleLog()
  }
})
```

Comment: Actually the fiddle link you gave shows that you assign api data to your vue data. You can see them in DOM.

You see null in your console log because while you are trying to receieve your data it console.logs your name which is equal to null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code actually looks (nearly) fine. The only thing you have to consider is, that you work with Promises in the `getData` function. That means, that you have to return the promise in your `getData` function and run the `consoleLog` function after the Promise resolved, like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/93z4wrba/3/

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    name: null,
    height: null
  },
  methods: {
    getData() {
      return fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/people/1')
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
          this.name = data.name;
          this.height = data.height;
        })
    },
    consoleLog() {
      console.log(this.name, this.height);
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getData()
      .then(() => {
        this.consoleLog()
      })
  }
})
```

Maybe consider switching to `async/await`, which makes the code a bit more readable.

Comment: Brilliant thanks for your help @tho-masn